# Erro quando tento dar CREATE em uma tabela PROGRESS 4GL

Tags: progress-4gl

Boa tarde. Novo no Progress aqui e e estou com um problema que não acontecia anteriormente. Quando eu criava uma nova linha em tabelas ou em tabelas temporárias, era só usar o CREATE [tabela]. Agora, nas últimas tabelas que eu tentei, tem dado um erro estranho.
Primeiro aparece o seguinte: ORACLE error -2289 see "ORACLE Error Messages and Codes Manual".(1252)
Depois de clicar em OK, aparece o seguinte erro: **a sequência não existe

O código que eu escrevi não é muito grande e é bem simples, então eu realmente não sei o problema.
A parte do create é a seguinte.

```
IF quantidade = 1 THEN DO:
        ...
    END.
    ELSE DO:
        create plan_embal.
        ASSIGN
        plan_embal.cod_emit = pi-cod-emit
        plan_embal.item = pc-item
        plan_embal.observacoes = pc-observacoes
        .
    END.
```

Comment: *"a sequência não existe"* pela mensagem falta uma sequence para essa tabela

Answer (score 0):

Verificamos tudo aqui e notamos que a sequência estava com nome diferente da tabela. Ao alterarmos isto, colocando a sequencia como o mesmo nome da tabela acrescido de _SEQ, tudo funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado.